# Mapbox new API and image compression

Tags: image, api, compression, mapbox

It seems that mapbox use a new API with the new mapbox studio online, for example:

```
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/outdoors-v9/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=mapboxAccessToken;
```

In the "old time", it was easy to add .jpg70 for example after {y} but with this new url, it doesn't work anymore.

Does anyone know how it works with this new api ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got an answer from Mapbox.

The compression on the new mapbox Studio Style (online) are done automatically in jpg or webp depending on the browser. But it's only works with raster tile like Mapbox satellite-streets.

If you are designing a map on the mapbox studio without any raster layer, the trick is to upload a geotiff with for example a plain color on the background, assign it to the desired style and put the opacity to 0.01. Then the compression will work !

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox.js has options to set the image format of tiles.  This may not be the *new* API you are referring to.  Please clarify if you are using `mapbox.js` or `mapbox-gl.js`.

See [`tileLayer.setFormat(format)`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.4.0/l-mapbox-tilelayer/#section-tilelayer-setformat).  Also, see the working [example of Low bandwidth maps](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/low-bandwidth/) from Mapbox.

```
// Downsample tiles for faster loading times on slow
// internet connections
var layer = L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.streets', {
    format: 'jpg70'
});
```

Comment: Actually I'm using the "original" leaflet. I need to try mapbox.js but I'm not sure it will work with the new "v9 maps"  (like mapbox/streets-v9). It seems that the doc of the api and mapbox.js wasn't updated ?